# install subversion (svn) via ssh

Tags: svn, ssh, installation, godaddy

I have a godaddy shared server with ssh enabled. Is it possible to install svn via ssh? If not has anyone found any other ways?

Answer (score 1):

If it isn't already there (`which svn` to check) and you have access to build tools (`which make`, `which gcc`) and you have enough disk space, you should be able to build it and install inside your shared space. (At the `./configure` step, you'll specify the install directory with something like `--path=/home/yourusername/bin/`.) Then you'll just need to add the directory to which you installed it to your `$PATH`, and you're good to go.

I realize that's a pretty broad sketch, but first you'll want to check that the tools are there, then do more specific research on the installation itself.

Comment: Worth noting: I'm assuming here that you're trying to install the `svn` *client*. See rmarimon's answer for the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitively install svn.  The question is then how would you access that SVN afterwards.  There are three basic ways to access svn (taken from the SVN manual):

- apache + mod_dav_svn
- svnserver
- svnserver over ssh

Choosing between the three will depend on what you can actually change on the shared server.  I would start by trying apache + mod_dav_svn, as it is the most flexible.  This will only work if you can load the mod_dav_svn module for apache.  Next try svnserver.  You might not be able to use svnserver over ssh, as it would require everyone to have a different account on the shared server which might not be possible in your case.

Check this link for further information [access options](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.overview.tbl-1).